# Как сделать замену регулярным выражением с помощью jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.
Есть разметка

```
<b id="idname">some_content</b>
```

Как превратить ее в

```
<b id="idname">some_content2</b>
```

Регуляркой?

```
$("#elementID").html("another string");
```

В моем случае не совсем подохдит.
Спасибо.

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под регулярным выражением???

Comment: Что-то типо этого <b(.*?)b>. Что бы захватить элемент прямо, без "проникновения" в DOM

Comment: А вы не думали просто текст в элементе менять?

Answer (score 0):

ну чтож, по вопросам желающих -поиграем в угадайку

```js
document.body.innerHTML = '<b id="idname">some_content</b>'
void function () {
 let i = 0
 function foo() {
  var idname = idname || document.getElementById('idname')
  let str = `some_content_${i}`
  let tmp_d = document.createElement('div')
  tmp_d.innerHTML = idname.outerHTML.replace(/(?![^>]+>)(.*)(?=<[^>]+>)/g, `>${str}`)
  idname.parentElement.replaceChild(tmp_d.childNodes[0], idname)
  i++
  if (i > 20) clearInterval(intervalID)
 }
 let intervalID = setInterval(foo, 1000)
}()
```

Comment: Ответ должен содержать четкую информацию по теме, а не беспорядочный поток мыслей. "Разметка" - абсолютно корректный термин для той последовательности символов, которую привел автор.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight следуя вашей логике: до слова стоп я доказываю, что изменение РАЗМЕТКИ через регулярку невозможно - ответ не абсолютно верен, но корректен. а фраза ©Что бы захватить элемент прямо, без "проникновения" в DOM - тоже не смущает вас?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, и да, не понимаю вашей фанатичной категоричности, учитывая наличие возможности редактирования ответа.